# Are there any good tutorials for NetBSD and daemontools?

Tags: bsd, netbsd, daemontools

I'm looking for some good resources on running `daemontools` on a NetBSD box. I've installed the binary package via `pkg_add`, but I can't seem to find an `rc` script for starting, e.g., `svscan`. I'm mostly a Linux and FreeBSD user, and this is the sort of thing I would expect to find after an install. Did I just look in the wrong place? Should I be building from source to find those sorts of extras? Is there a good guide somewhere that covers things like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I once did this on OpenBSD and followed http://openbsd.totorux.info/openbsd-wiki.org/index.php/Installing_Daemontools

Maybe it can help under NetBSD, too?

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Bernstein daemontools installs by way of the `package/run` program, invoked by the `package/install` program.  This determines whether the operating system uses System 5 `rc` or the old BSD `rc`, and updates either `/etc/inittab` or `/etc/rc.local` accordingly.

van Smoorenburg `rc` (from Linux operating systems) is a portability nightmare, and Mewburn `rc` (as used nowadays on FreeBSD and NetBSD) had barely (just under 6 months) been brought out for NetBSD and didn't exist at all on other BSDs when daemontools 0.76 came out in July 2001.

Whereas, on the other hand, `/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past, and on operating systems such as Ubuntu Linux `/etc/rc.local` has actually been superseded *thrice over* — by van Smoorenburg `rc`, then by upstart, and then by systemd.  ([It's a mere *twice over* superseded on CentOS.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247543/5132))

That leaves pretty much nothing in vanilla Bernstein daemontools.

Various people have addressed this deficit over the years.

- [Norikatsu Shigemura made a Mewburn `rc` file for FreeBSD](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports?view=revision&revision=112506) in 2004.
- Jim Caroll published upstart job files for daemontools in 2006.
- Gerrit Pape made systemd service unit files for daemontools for the "daemontools-run" package that xe maintains for Debian Linux in 2014.

Shigemura's Mewburn `rc` script from the start incorporated the knowledge that `svscanboot` is a thing of the past, too.  It could handle invoking a log dæmon for the output of `svscan` (and its `supervise` children) itself.  By 2007, it had no need for `readproctitle` at all.

[The nosh toolset](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/) can handle daemontools services, and has a `svscan`-compatible mode of operation as well as [a package that provides Mewburn `rc` files](https://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/freebsd-binary-packages.html#rc) for running the nosh service manager and service scanner under Mewburn `rc`.  For more information, look in the *nosh Guide* in the chapter entitled "Compatible old-style startup", accessible with

```
xdg-open /usr/local/share/doc/nosh/svscan-startup.html
```

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The known problems with System 5 `rc`*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/system-5-rc-problems.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jim Caroll (2006).  [*DaemontoolsUpstartConfig*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DaemontoolsUpstartConfig).  Upstart wiki.
- Joern Heissler (2014-06-19).  [*daemontools-run: Add systemd support*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=752075).  Debian Bug #752075.
- Andrew George Hammond (2007-04-17). [*sysutils/daemontools svscan output to multilog would be a nice option*](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111749).  FreeBSD bug #111749.
- [*daemontools*](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/daemontools).  Debian package tracker.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (2001).  [*How to install daemontools*](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/install.html).  daemontools.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for daemontools, but could be an alternative that works/compiles in netbsd: https://immortal.run/source/ There is no current port but  works straight forward